# paused plan not showing in firestore stripe subscriptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I have stripe successfully set up with my firebase react app. I just turned on this feature to `pause subscriptions` in stripe. So this works fine in my billing manage subscription prebuilt checkout portal in stripe. However, in firebase, it does not update the status to paused or anything. When I cancel the plan, it updates it to `cancelled`, when it is active, it says `active`, but when it is paused, nothing changes! I need this parameter to show up somewhere so I can allow the user to only access certain pages. how is this possible?

[image]

it shows it is `trialing`, but the actual status is paused. how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Pausing a subscription doesn't update its status, instead you'd look at the subscription's [pause collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pause_collection-behavior) hash. If `pause_collection.behavior` is not empty, then the subscription is paused.